# AttributeError: 'df' object has no attribute 'dtype'

Tags: python

I was importing an xlsx file to Google Colab using code

```
df = pd.ExcelFile('/content/gdrive/My Drive/df.xlsx')
```

and encountered error

> AttributeError: 'ExcelFile' object has no attribute 'dtype'.

I was expecting df4 to be a DataFrame and check its shape. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Read it using `pd.read_excel` instead of `pd.ExcelFile`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), the proper way to read the excel file is:

```
dfs = pd.read_excel(file_name, sheet_name=None)
```